# Extract Text Data from Document using Apache Tika

Tags: apache-tika, data-extraction

I am looking for a tool to extract text data from a document.  Specifically, I would like to be able to extract metadata from invoices such as Invoice Number, Vendor Name, Invoice Date, Due Date, Amount Due, etc.  Since the invoices coming in are from my vendors the metadata I listed will be located on different areas of the document.  I have not been able to determine if Tika can search for a keyword in the document such as INVOICE and then extract the invoice number.  I would like to be able to extract this data then push the document and metadata to a document management system such as SharePoint or Alfresco.  Does anyone have experience with Tika and do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Extract all the text with Tika and then search it for the fields/patterns you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ephesoft and alfresco.
Using ephesoft : you can extract data.
Using alfresco : you can store extracted data with document.
Its good compare to Tika.
Watch below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soV-9GGhuBg

Comment: Hi Krutik,

I had Ephesoft community set up and connected it to Alfresco.  The issue we have is the community edition is difficult to work with and it is cumbersome to set up a document for extraction.  I an looming for other options, but initially Ephesoft was my first option.

Comment: F_puras, if I extract all text do you think it would be possible to search key words then extract such as invoive them extract the invoice number based on a regexp?

Comment: Yes its possible.I guess ephesoft has many option for OCR and many more things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but will be useful for other visitors to know about Algodocs, which also offers a free subscription forever: https://algodocs.com.
Algodocs offers all-in-one solution, i.e. you can extract specific fields as you need or table rows from images or PDF files with hundreds of pages.